# Pandemic--epidemics with eradicated diseases

Tags: pandemic

If an Epidemic card is drawn, but the card from the infection deck that is then drawn has an eradicated disease on it, is it necessary to shift the infection rate forward--or does the fact that the disease is eradicated mean that the epidemic has been avoided? Is it necessary to intensify by shuffling the infection discards and putting them on top of the infection deck in this case?

Answer (score 15):

Yes, you still move the infection rate forward and intensify by shuffling the discards. The only thing that eradicating a disease does is prevent you from placing more cubes of that disease on the board.